# How to resolve Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 (while processing android/gesture/GestureUtils.class)

Tags: android, adt

When i try to launch my android app I get the following error :

```
2016-04-05 13:05:57 - myApp] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2016-04-05 13:05:57 - myApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2016-04-05 13:20:28 - myApp] Dx
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
[2016-04-05 13:20:28 - myApp] Dx expected type int[] but found float[]

[2016-04-05 13:20:28 - myApp] Dx ...at bytecode offset 0000001a
locals[0000]: [F
locals[0001]: <invalid>
locals[0002]: <invalid>
locals[0003]: [[F
locals[0004]: <invalid>
locals[0005]: <invalid>
locals[0006]: <invalid>
...while working on block 0018
...while working on method computeCoVariance:([F)[[F
...while processing computeCoVariance ([F)[[F
...while processing android/gesture/GestureUtils.class

[2016-04-05 13:20:28 - myApp] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2016-04-05 13:20:28 - myApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2016-04-05 13:22:42 - myApp] Dx
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION:
[2016-04-05 13:22:42 - myApp] Dx expected type int[] but found float[]

[2016-04-05 13:22:42 - myApp] Dx ...at bytecode offset 0000001a
locals[0000]: [F
locals[0001]: <invalid>
locals[0002]: <invalid>
locals[0003]: [[F
locals[0004]: <invalid>
locals[0005]: <invalid>
locals[0006]: <invalid>
...while working on block 0018
...while working on method computeCoVariance:([F)[[F
...while processing computeCoVariance ([F)[[F
...while processing android/gesture/GestureUtils.class

[2016-04-05 13:22:42 - myApp] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2016-04-05 13:22:42 - myApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I have tried to resolve that by checking redundancy in project classes/packages
with any chance ..

Can someone help me .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !

I have included two definitions of GestureUtils.class because I have used the hidden pack framework.jar which has this conflict with android sdk ..